# How does Custom Authorizer and Lambda function work with api endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am new to node.js and also API gateway thing.
I have deployed my rest api on amazon api gateway and been reading the docs on amazon api gateway in order to secure my deployed API. I am trying to get my head around custom authorizer and lambda function by reading the docs but when I see my deployed api with "integration type" as HTTP Proxy, 
1) I get confused as to how do I make the same deployment a lambda integration?

2) I have my business logic where if the user making calls to my api is validated through my backend then only access to resources is given to them.

3) Can I write the same logic to validate the users in that lambda function and give it to custom authorizer? ( something on the lines of OAuth)

4) Will custom authorizer then invoke the logic and manage auth to resources?

So far I have an API deployed on gateway and I can make request with api key as well.
Please lemme know, If I am anywhere wrong with my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda Integration and Custom Authorizers are two separate things. Lambda Integration is an API Gateway method that relies on a Lambda function to process a request and return a result. Custom Authorizers is a Lambda function that API Gateway uses simply to determine if the caller has access to call the API endpoint. The Custom Authorizer would be called, and the authorization verified, before the request is passed along to a Lambda Integration function or a back-end HTTP service, etc. You wouldn't need to "make the same deployment a Lambda integration" in order to use Custom Authorizers.

Your other questions are a bit vague and I think stem from a misunderstanding of the way Custom Authorizers work. Hopefully I have cleared that up and it makes more sense to you now.

Comment: This is a great explanation. One thing I've been curious about: where does the AWS Gateway cache query happen? Before or after Custom Authorization?

Comment: Thanks a lot Mark for that explaination, sorry for the trouble with my vague question but those questions rose from my complex requirement which I have at hand